# How to grab a object property from json with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am getting my head around lodash for js and trying to select the object property with the name 'one' from this object by using the id key:

```
{
   "one": {
      "id":"peter",
      "somevalue":1
         },
   "two": {
      "id":"john",
      "somevalue":1
   }

}
```

So as a result I would like:

```
{
   "id":"peter",
   "somevalue":1
}
```

Sorry I updated the question:
How can I accomplish this with lodash returning this result based on the name in this case 'one' by using the key , id='peter'?

Comment: Why don't you access it directly using plain javascript `object.one`?

Comment: You *don't* grab properties from JSON, you parse the JSON and then grab properties from the resulting object.

Comment: sorry I updated the question see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Lodash` (#1):

```
const value = _.find(obj, prop => prop.id === 'peter');
```

With `Lodash` (#2):

```
const value = _.find(obj, {id: 'peter'});
```

With `Lodash` (#3): (credit to hughes)

```
const value = _.find(obj, 'id', 'peter');
```

Plain JS:

```
const key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].id === 'peter');
const value  obj[key];
```

Future JS:

```
const value = Object.values(obj).find(prop => prop.id === 'peter');
```

Comment: I would point out also a third lodash option that isn't very well documented. If you do not need a complex predicate object or function, you can query for an exact value:  `_.find(obj, 'id', 'peter')`

Answer (score 1):

More documentation on filter here: https://lodash.com/docs#filter

```js
var obj = {
   "one": {
      "id":"peter",
      "somevalue":1
         },
   "two": {
      "id":"john",
      "somevalue":1
   }

};

console.log(_.filter(obj, {id:"peter"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```